# Which will consume less resources? Sub query or two queries using programming language

Tags: php, mysql

here is Livi
I am working on project in which database is too much huge and i have fear that db query optimization must be done there.
I am working on DB and it has almost billions of records in tables and i am searching fast method which consume less resoureces from database server and web server.
At the time, i am using 2 queries to select data from tables like

```
result1 = select data_id from table1 where id<1000
```

and than by using php code i fetch data and than again run query to fetch data like

```
select * from table2 where data_id1<result1
```

and i can also use this as sub query.

i have question that which method will be best for me as i told that it have very big database could be in GB's.

Comment: Why not use `JOIN`s?

Comment: I would avoid using your PHP application logic to store intermediate database results.  The MySQL engine was built to handle database stuff; let it do what it was designed to do.

Comment: by using joins, loading of page became high.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually database size is too much and cache memory became low according to my knowledge.

Comment: Billions of records rarely cause performance issues on a properly tuned database; billions of queries do cause issues

Comment: json files can help out? like 
i create json file wtih each having 1 million records  and store json record in separate table... instead of getting record from database, read json file name from table and then find it out from json file. is this good for system? i know this will cuase updation problem in database but everyday once we will update json files..

Comment: json?!? - You're joking right? Large volumes of json data will be a serious memory overhead that will break your system like a twig.... you're going to be transferring all your logic form a database (a tool designed for data searching) to PHP (__not__ a tool designed for data searching), so you're going to end up with slow performance

Comment: JOINS in your database queries is the correct approach to this problem.... if you've defined your tables correctly, with appropriate indexes, then your database access should be highly efficient across the two tables..... if you haven't defined things well, then it can be bad.... but your question tells us nothing about the table structures, indexes, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumes that your first query yields m record then you have to run the second query m times. The same with using subquery.
In resource consuming, I think the 2 approaches has no different, you either put the heavy lifting in database or webserver.
In the 2 queries method: you put all the weight of process data to the webserver and in the sub query method all the weight goes to the database server.
To conclusion, 2 queries ~ 1 query and 1 subquery. The decision is up to you to choose where to put the weight on (it should be on webserver in my oppinion due to your huge database)
Regards,